# Three task parallel computation

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++14

I have a loop that goes through tens of millions of cycles, each cycle corresponding to a row of data file I'm reading. There are three sequential computations inside the loop. Loosely speaking, we can label them (a) read data, (b) process data, (c) accumulate results. (a), (b), and (c) take about the same time individually. (b) depends on (a), and (c) depends on (a) and (b). I think that if I make the program run in 3 threads, with each thread behind by one computation from it's neighbor, I can get about a factor of 3 speedup. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with multithreading.

The way I see the design is like this:

1. The first reads row `n` (a);
2. When this is done, the first thread processes the row (b), and at the same time the second thread reads row `n+1`;
3. When the second thread is done reading row `n+1`, it starts processing it, and the third thread reads row `n+2`. If the first thread is done with (b) it moves on the (c).

In other words, the sequence of steps is like this:

```
1a
1b 2a
1c 2b 3a
1a 2c 3b
1b 2a 3c
1c 2b 3a
```

and so on.

So, a single row always stays on the same thread. The next thread starts a new row when it's done with it's own and the other two threads have read the two preceding rows.

Can somebody help me set this up? These are the only constraints:

- b_n can only start when a_n is done
- c_n can only start when b_n is done
- a_n can only start when a_(n-1) and a_(n-2) are done (since we have 3 threads, and it's faster to read sequentially)

I also understand that each thread will have to have independent storage.

Forgot to mention: each row is processed entirely independently.

Comment: Aside from my clarification question. Unless your per-row calculations are CPU intensive, your bottle-neck will be reading the file and you're unlikely to obtain any significant concurrency. (The purpose of multi-threading is concurrency, it doesn't "speed up" anything.)

Comment: As I mentioned, (a), (b), and (c) take about equal time. Actually, (a), which is the reading part, takes a bit less than (b).

Comment: Rather than multiple threads reading the same file, you might be better off  using a single thread dedicated to reading the file and placing data onto a processing queue for another thread(s). Essentially pipe-lining the work.

Comment: @CraigYoung If I take the dedicated reading thread approach, how do I coordinate data availability with the processing threads?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not quite familiar with the specifics, but I'd investigate along the following lines: use move-semantics to transfer an object onto a shared queue. I'd look into the possibility of using a lock-free queue. The processing would take objects off the queue while something is available and sleep while empty (sleep would need multiple wake-up triggers: data added to queue, or thread needs to be terminated).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the questiom may be rephrased as "how to improve program performance", and that the file is a sequential file residing on a hard disk:

Do not read record by record, but read many (say 1000000) records as a large chunk of data, and then retrieve the records from the buffer for processing.

A little test with a compiled C program on a system with i5-3220M CPU and 8GB RAM and SSD drive:

Reading a file of 14 million 80 byte records one by on took around 15 seconds, while reading the file in chunks of 1000000 records was just subsecond.

I would not be surprised if the relative improvement is larger for a mechanical disk.

I would also not be surprised if the benefits of a multithread processing approach would not justify its development costs.